# How do I deploy editable content files for a Winforms desktop app?

Tags: .net, winforms, setup-deployment

I have a desktop app which includes some content files. Currently the files are not editable where they are deployed (App Folder\Templates).

I'm looking for documentation or info on how to deploy with these files where the user is able to open them and edit them.

These are text files. And would be opened outside my app with either notepad or something else.

I currently use MSI setup and Windows Store deployments.

Comment: no, I'm deploying template files, which users should be able to modify

Comment: What do you mean by "template" files which should be able to "modify"? I assume you have some file having specific extension like ".xyz" and you want to let the user double click on the file and open it in an application like "notepad.exe". Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: it's just a text file, but windows security will not let the user modify it.

Comment: Maybe you want to install your config files to %appdata% folder?  There you shouldn't have problems with editing.

Comment: maybe (I look into that), but they are not config files. Config are typically only changed once. They are templates, just like Visual Studio has templates.

Comment: %appdata% folder works, users can modify them. @Sven if you make an answer, I'll give you credit and elaborate with some links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install it to the %appdata% folder instead, users should be able to edit the template files.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67159d80-eacb-41d9-911b-7f520715a074/how-to-use-the-appdata-folder?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/318177/what-is-the-appdata-folder-in-windows/